# How to populate datasource for listview using api response in react native?

Tags: listview, react-native

My Api returns me a response exactly like the const "devices" defined below. If i don't call the api, i am getting the listview properly populated with single row of data, but if i populate the datasource using Api response, i am getting empty 160 rows.

Whats wrong with my setState?

```js
    const devices = [
        {
            "DeviceID": 4,
            "DeviceCode": "ODPRC-HB-4",
            "ContactName": "Sudhir",
            "GPS_Lat_Long": "15.396863, 74.012382",
            "DeviceName": "Sudhirs Device"
        }
    ];

    class Devices extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
        });
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(devices)
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDeviceList();
    }

    getDeviceList() {
        let request = new Request('https://myapiWithQueryString.com');
        request.addHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});  
        RNETWORK.get(request, () => {
        }, (response) => {
            if (response.getError()) {
                alert(response.getError().message);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(response.getBodyString())

                });
                alert(response.getBodyString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact value of response.getBodyString() ? An array or a string ?

Comment: exactly like this... 
[
        {
            "DeviceID": 4,
            "DeviceCode": "ODPRC-HB-4",
            "ContactName": "Sudhir",
            "GPS_Lat_Long": "15.396863, 74.012382",
            "DeviceName": "Sudhirs Device"
        }
    ]

Comment: at the initial, there will be no data with devices, so how did u handle that?
If you could share that will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(JSON.parse(response.getB‌​odyString()))
```

Note: I am assuming getBodyString actually returns something because I don't recall that method existing in the response interface.

Comment: this didnt work. btw i am using react-native-netclient library for making api calls. getBodyString() returns me the json which i have commented on my question

Comment: It worked this way. Thank you buddy.. please update the answer .

dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(JSON.parse(response.getBodyString()))

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I actually meant to write that. Glad it worked!